# FOSBundle redirect loop

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using SF2 together with FOS user bundle.

```
security:
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt|error)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    false

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

If I set my `main: anonymous: false` to `true`, I no longer get a redirect loop, but then people don't need to be logged in to access everything (which they should be!)

I *think* the `access_control` has an entry for the `^/login` route so that people don't need to be authenticated, but I suspect it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this statement:

```
 anonymous:    false
```

this is no longer valid:

```
  - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Therefore the framework can't redirect to the login which causes the redirect loop (FOS needs anonymous to be true in order to work properly)
... I don't know if it works but you could try to set

```
{ path: ^/*, role: ROLE_USER }
```

as the first or last line of the assetic control,... no guarantee it works, this is would I would try in order to create the result you are looking for